# Copying Clipboard text including tables to microsoft word (.docx) file

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Dim objApp As Word.Application
        Dim objDoc As Word.Document
        objApp = New Word.Application()
        objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\bn\Desktop\DCIM\lol.docx")
        objDoc.Activate()
        objApp.Selection.TypeText(My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText)
            objDoc.SaveAs("C:\Users\bn\Desktop\DCIM\lol2.docx")
        objDoc.Close()
        objApp.Quit()
        objDoc = Nothing
        objApp = Nothing
```

I used above code to create a microsoft word file containing clipboard texts which contains table. But it gives me error. I think it is because of "objApp.Selection.TypeText(My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText)" doesnt accept tables but only text. I want file to be created as it is I have copied which includes tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**`Selection.PasteAndFormat()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.pasteandformat.aspx) instead. It lets you specify in what format the copied content should be pasted.

By specifying `WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting` it will retain the original formatting of the pasted content.

```
objApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```